# error occure like Use the `initWithVideoIdentifier:` method instead

Tags: ios

I am using following code that will work fine with me in ios 6 but when i move to ios 8 it will not work properly for me ...

XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:sc.plyUrl];

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoPlayerViewController animated:YES];
```

Is there any problem with xcdyoutubekit or something wrong with my code....
please help...Any One....

Comment: Did you update `xcdyoutubekit`,as they have solved it in their latest version.

Comment: yes i am using xcdyoutubekit 2.0.3

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you should not be using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoPlayerViewController animated:YES]` but `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of XCDYouTubeKit (2.0.3) and the latest version of Xcode (6.1.1).